# to download a page as pdf file and save in a local folder in C#

Tags: c#

```
protected void btn_download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=foo.pdf");
    string filePath = Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) + " \\Member\\Attachments" ;
    Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
    Response.End(); 
}
```

I used the above link code to download a webpage to a pdf file and save in a local file. But i am getting the error as access to the path is denied. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Missing local file name in filePath variable. Append file name to it. And make sure that you attachment directory have permission to access files for IIS users.

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) + " \\Member\\Attachments\\foo.pdf" ; \\Append your file name here.
```

Comment: Thank u..may i know what this foo.pdf is? there should be a filename named foo.pdf in that location?

Comment: yes. your actual file name that is present at that physical location. foo.pdf is just for example

Comment: I tried that but i am getting that foo.pdf file downloaded. but what i want is the page under which the download button is there to be downloaded as pdf. the download button is inside a datalist for now. and i want the contents of that datalist which is like a certificate to be downloaded as pdf.

Comment: That is your other problem. i had given my answer for this question. You can create other question for your different problem.